# center gridview columns in row

Tags: android, gridview, center, children

I have a gridview, with a set number of columns (let's say, 5). However, if I have 6 images set in my image adapter, the 6th one automatically goes to a new row, and is assigned the first column. The behavior I am looking for would be to automatically (or programmatically, somehow) center that extra child element in the new row... like this for example:

```
A B C D E
    F
```

Here is the XML that I have for the gridview:

```
<GridView android:id="@+id/gridview" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:columnWidth="10dip"
android:numColumns="10" android:horizontalSpacing="10dip"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:verticalSpacing="3dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/TopLayout"
android:layout_gravity="center"></GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the number of cols for a given row. The only trick I can think of is to use an odd number of columns and insert void entries in the list your adapter is based on. E.g. if you have 5 cols and 6 images, insert 2 void entries at positions 5 and 6 so your last image will be centered.

Comment: so this is the programmatic answer... ok... is it possible to set my adapter's content to be mixed (e.g.: images in specific spots, and empty text views for example, as the spacers), or do they all have to be the same type?

Comment: The content of each cell is generated in the getView() method of your adapter and there can be only one. However you can code it to react differently to specific situations. For example, if your Bitmap is null, then the text should be centered. But you have to deal with it programmatically, not with xml.